# getting val() to use in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, sessionstorage

The key line in the script is`var tmp = $(this).parent().find('select').val();`

and `tmp` returns, for example, `"s1"` (including the quotes) as seen in the console, which is what is expected. tmp will have different values depending on what is picked on the page.

But `sessionStorage.tmp = 2` created a key:value pair of ``tmp:2, not`s1:2`.

How do I create a sessionStorage object `s1` with value `2`?

Seems like this should be simple. I tried tmp = tmp.toString(); and a million other things, but I'm too much of a newbie to figure this out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `string` as a property name you'll have to use a construct like this:

```
sessionStorage[tmp] = 2
```

This seems to be called **bracket notation** you can find more details about it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours trying different things. How would I have found this or what is this called? Or what is the concept?

Comment: @Greg This is just JavaScript's syntax and the concept is using a `string` as an object's key or object's property name. It is probably mentioned in many introductory JavaScript courses.

Comment: @Greg I've edited my answer to include more details.

Comment: I had looked at the page you added, but didn't make the leap to getting rid of the quotes. In other works, I'm sure I tried `sessionStorage["tmp"] = 2`. Hope this will sink in to my brain.

Comment: @Taplar. I don't think that works, that's what I started with. A session variable named `tmp` is created, not one named `s1`. That's what I spent hours trying to sort out.

Comment: @Greg https://jsfiddle.net/kk9nusyf/1/  The api expressly lays out the usage of getItem and setItem.  https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @Taplar I stand corrected. Maybe I can revisit this later and find out what didn't work for me.